# Javascript Search for String Starting at End & Stopping at Another String

Tags: javascript

I have a string like this:

`The planet is very big and the planet is heavy.`

Using Javascript, I would like to search for a string starting from the end and stopping at another string.

An example would be, start at the word `heavy`, search for the word `planet`, but stop at the word `big`. The second instance of `planet` in this example is what I want, not the first. Therefore if there is not an instance of `planet` between `big` and `heavy` then I want to yield an indexOf -1.

Thanks.

Edit: I can accomplish this by splitting my string on the word I want than searching the second element of the array for my text but I was wondering if there was a function to do this.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: If you've already found a solution, the question shouldn't be phrased "how do I..." What's wrong with your solution? Why do you want an alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could split on the word "big" and then only lastIndexOf from the last subsstring group.

IE:

```
function foo(input,search,stopWord){
    //Split the input
    var arr=input.split(stopWord);

    //return only from last substring group
    return arr[arr.length-1].lastIndexOf(search);
}
foo("The planet is very big and the planet is heavy.","planet","big");
```

Does that give you the result you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
var startIdx = string.lastIndexOf('big');
var grabIdx = string.lastIndexOf('planet');
(startIdx < grabIdx)?grabIdx: -1)
```

Comment: Since he wants to stop searching at the splitter word, he wouldn't want to search all the substrings - only the last one.

Comment: Splitter would be " ". So search backwards and if you hit "big" end.

Comment: But ya lastIndexOf or IndexOf is much more efficient.

Comment: Ah I see where you were going with it. My only critique would be the return value is going to be a word count from the end of the input, not a character count as is the standard. But yeah, this could work.

Comment: Added a new method that seems most efficient to me. There may be some checks required by you get the idea.

Comment: startIdx would have to be lastIndexOf('big') also in case there were more than one occurrence of the string. For example,
_The planet is very big and the planet has big mountains_